# Standard Swipe Fling?

Tags: android

I have a GestureDetector to capture onFling events. Now I'm just using if velocityX > 150... then right to left swipe, it's a bit subjective and doesn't work all that well. I was wondering if there was a system standard for detecting right->left and left->right swipe flings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the default ViewConfiguration setting.

```
final ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration
        .get(getContext());

mMinimumVelocity = configuration.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();
```